# PostgreSQL SQL/XML dynamic tagname generation

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I'm dynamically generating the tag names as the actual data set consists of many elements.
I need to display the date of the data as a the top element.

This is what I have so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo
AS
(SELECT '2021-12-01' as date, 'Sell' as type, 123 as qty
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-12-01' as date, 'Buy' as type, 456 as qty
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-12-02' as date, 'Sell' as type, 789 as qty
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-12-02' as date, 'Buy' as type, 987 as qty);

SELECT * FROM foo;

|date        |type   |qty  |
|------------|-------|-----|
|"2021-12-01"| "Sell"|  123|
|"2021-12-01"| "Buy" |  456|
|"2021-12-02"| "Sell"|  789|
|"2021-12-02"| "Buy" |  987|

SELECT xmlelement(name "Trades", xmlagg(x)) 
FROM (SELECT format('<%3$s>%4$s</%3$s><%1$s>%2$s</%1$s>', 
                   type, 
                   xmlagg(xmlelement(name "Quantity", qty)),
                   'Date',
                   date)::xml x 
        FROM foo group by type,date
        ORDER BY date ASC) s;
```

This produces following XML:

```xml
<Trades>
    <Date>2021-12-01</Date>
    <Sell>
        <Quantity>123</Quantity>
    </Sell>
    <Date>2021-12-01</Date>
    <Buy>
        <Quantity>456</Quantity>
    </Buy>
    <Date>2021-12-02</Date>
    <Buy>
        <Quantity>987</Quantity>
    </Buy>
    <Date>2021-12-02</Date>
    <Sell>
        <Quantity>789</Quantity>
    </Sell>
</Trades>
```

The problem is the dates are repeating but I need to display it as the top element.
So my desired XML result is this:

```xml
<Trades>
    <Date>2021-12-01</Date>
        <Sell>
            <Quantity>123</Quantity>
        </Sell>
        <Buy>
            <Quantity>456</Quantity>
        </Buy>
    <Date>2021-12-02</Date>
        <Buy>
            <Quantity>987</Quantity>
        </Buy>
        <Sell>
            <Quantity>789</Quantity>
        </Sell>
</Trades>
```

Comment: In theory the order of tags in an XML is meaningless, so this seems like  a strange format to begin with. I would expect the `<Date>` tag to be _inside_ the `<Sell>` tag.

Comment: This is used by a 3rd party for reporting purposes. Unfortunately I have to follow their rules. For each date of the month they expect this kind of format.. I could use XMLConcat and string all 28-31 days together in separate queries, but there must be a more efficient way.